# Android Studio doesn't show my device in the "Device Chooser" dialog. I don't want to use the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I searched for the answer before asking. They weren't satisfactory.

**Environment and what I did so far:**

- My device is Xiaomi Redmi 2. I have enabled USB Debugging in my device.
- My phone uses a Cyanogen mode with 5.1.1 installed ( Lollipop ) and not 4.4 ( Kit-Kat )
- It is also connected as a media device as asked in an answer
- I'm running android studio on Windows 8.1.

  - I don't want to change my OS if that's possible.
- Minimum level it is set to be API Level 15 so all the devices with ICS will be supported.

**Questions:**

- Do I need to install a driver and if yes, what driver do I need to install to make it work?
- If I need it how do I use it?
- Where do I get it from?

I have to mention that I am using this site for the first time so I might not know the best way to search. 
Any tips on that?

Comment: Welcome, Yes you definitely need drivers for most of the Android devices to connect to the adb on a windows machine. 1.) Search for Your devices drivers. 2.) Download and install them. 3.) Try again if failed. 4.)  Connect your device and test the app.

Comment: have you tried other device ? see if other device is working good, then it your device driver.

Comment: thanks sai, it was the driver. it worked finally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just be that the MTP mode isn't supported. Try changing your usb connection to PTP in your device's usb connection settings.

Comment: you were right changed to PTP and it worked. Driver also got auto installed so I didn't have to install it

Comment: =) Glad to hear. The same thing happened to me a little while back. Don't forget to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [Android Studio User Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html).

If you are developing on Windows and would like to connect a device to test your applications, then you need to install the appropriate USB driver.

Find the appropriate driver for your device from the [OEM drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#Drivers) table.

Once you've downloaded your USB driver, follow the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#Win7) to install or upgrade the driver, and whether you're installing for the first time or upgrading an existing driver.

Answer (score 0):

Update your android studio and your android project :

Android Studio > SDK Manager (top right of the ide) > Launch Standalone SDK Manager > uncheck the 'installed' checkbox > make sure you have all the recommended updates, tools and apis installed to your development machine.

3. Update your android project manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) on about line 20 usually to match the target SDK version you want to build for :

Answer (score 0):

You have to install ADB USB driver manually

Try the below link

http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/